# Problem with importing Quote Products in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Hi I am having a problem with importing Quote products in CRM 2011.

When I downloaded the template for import, the columns require that I state whether the product is a 'Write-in' or an 'Existing' product. Then there are an additional 2 columns: Write In, Existing.

On filling in the template with sample data for import, I wrote something like this:

Write-in |                    | New product |......
Existing | Existing Product 1 |             |.......

(The | is a new column )

I am assuming that when the product is a write-in product, you must enter a new product and when the product is an existing product, you write the name of an existing product in the system. The other columns are then left blank.

However, I am getting errors on import and I have no clue why :/ I am giving it the wrong data?

Also... the company does not make use of a Product List. Is there a way in which I can bypass its use since every time I enter a new product, I am asked to give the price list and this is not viable for the company since there are hundreds of products and the items and their prices change constantly so we cannot make use of a Product List especially when I am asked to enter a New Product List every time :/

Does anyone have a clue of what can be done? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, I can suggest the following.

1. Have a default price list, Onload of such forms, autofill that field with that PriceList.
2. Also, when quote is created, use JScript to say there is always going to be a write In product. (Then, you dont require the Product Lookup filled in).

Also, I dont know what kind of errors you get here, but when you specify an existing product, you also have to specify the UniOfMeasure or something. Make sure you have one supplied in your CSV.